# Need Dialog/Message Box component for C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I would like to find a good-looking implementation of C# / ASP.NET message/simple dialog box.

It should:

- be generated when I call something like showDialogBox() in my code, whenever I need to show it (simple C# interface)
- be modal.
- be visually appealing and customisable, including its size and position.
- be able to display at least OK button and a text field that can show HTML text.

I am interested in reasonably priced or free solutions.

**In short, please share links to C# ASP.NET DialogBox solutions you like!**

Comment: A modal message box can be easily implemented using JQuery, you don't need to pay for it! And it is fully customizable. Remember that javascript it is a client side technology and you cannot fire a js event whenever you prefer from you code behind. Have a look at JQuery UI for the modal dialog : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: Giorgio, I am very familiar with JQuery and has a tools for that. But I need to act from code behind, because it is codebehind that generates the message!

Comment: Using javascript from codebehind is generally a bad practice. If you need to pass something from your code to the page, just assign it to a control or a js variable and then pick it up with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AJAX Control Toolkit` and style it yourself (The example is not visually appealing IMO):

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

jQuery also has it's `Dialog` which can be skinned via the `Theme Roller`

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Both of them examples are free (You should not be paying for a fancy modal dialog), you could also create your own by using a `<div>` tag which holds your content and javascript to hide/show the tag.

Comment: Thanks Darren, looks promising.